# How i can display another image or text in another <aside> without clearing out the screen with the first uploaded picture?

Tags: php, html

I am having trouble with some PHP. I want to upload a picture, display it and after clicking "process", display something on the other side of the page. For example code, i just want to display "hello". When i try to do it, it clears the uploaded image.
Any pointer into right direction?

Much appreciated.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>


<body>
  
<div class="row">
<aside id="left">
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="file_to_upload" id="file_to_upload">
    <input type="submit" name="submits" id="upload_button" value="upload">
</form>

<div id="uploaded_pic">
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submits']))
{ 
$filepath = "images/upload" . $_FILES["file_to_upload"]["name"];

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file_to_upload"]["tmp_name"], $filepath)) 
{
echo "<img src=".$filepath." height=640 width=480 />";
} 
else 
{
echo "Problem uploading";
}

} 
  
?>
</div>
<div id="process-button">
    <form action="" method="POST" name="processing">
    <input type="submit" name="process_button" id="process_button" value="process">
</form>
</div>

</aside>

<aside id="right">

<?php
    if (array_key_exists('process_button',$_POST))
    {
        echo "hello";
    }
?>
</div>
</aside>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone concerned either because of a similar problem or pure interest - in this code the issue with clearing the screen was caused by the second form. It cleared the screen after submitting.
So i replaced the form with a simple button and onevent handler and it is working fine now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).